# Which of the clans are mortal?

Tags: ice-fantasy

In the TV series *Ice Fantasy* (幻城 in Chinese), there are mortals and immortals. The mortals seem to be regular humans (although they can possess magic) and the immortals live forever or a very long time, and often look noticeably different (for example, white hair regardless of age for the Ice Clan).

Clearly, the Ice Clan and the Fire Clan are immortals. But what about the others? The wording (albeit translated) of the description of the location of the leaves of the Six-Leaf Ice Star suggests that each piece was left with a mortal clan. And indeed, it certainly seems like the Healer Clan is mostly mortal, since Ka Suo is surprised that the leader has powers from the Immortal Kingdoms.

However, the Mermaid Clan is mentioned as having one leaf (I certainly *thought* they were immortal, since they have odd-colored hair and were in attendance at the Ice Kingdom events, and appear to be magical). Further, Xing Jiu is upset that Xing Gui supposedly can't live beyond 100 years, which would be an odd thing for a mortal to be upset about.

Which of these clans are mortal, and which are not?